# SVN Sync Changed to Sub Directory

Tags: svn, synchronization

I had a local directory named "repo_root" on Windows 7 which was synchronized with trunk folder of SVN. The trunk of SVN has two subdirectories named "work" and "documentation". So local repo_root directory also had two subdirectories from SVN (work and documentation). It was working fine for around six months. But today when I started my computer, the link of local directory repo_root to trunk folder was gone and local subdirectory work (inside repo_root) was linked to the trunk folder without my intervention. So I can not now do SVN-Update on repo_root folder. And if I do SVN-Update to subdirectory "work", two new subdirectories "work" and "documentation" are created withing local "work" directory.

It looks like a words mess, so any question regarding clarification of problem, please ask.
Thanks for prompt responses.

Br.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try SVN-Relocate for your repo_root directory to the trunk directory

Comment: thanks but svn-relocate is not available for repo_root directory because it does not have the svn link anymore